# 503 response from RubyGems

Tags: rubygems, google-cloud-platform

We're getting errors on our CI builds because fetching gems from rubygeme.org fails at some point. If i run locally a `bundle install`it fetches ok.

```
    Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: bad response Connection timed out 503 (http://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/gems/sprockets-helpers-1.1.0.gem)
```

This 503 responses only happen from time to time, although it could go on for a couple of hours. It leads me into thinking about problems with rubygems's cdn availability but it's strange that their status page doesn't mention anything and local `bundle install` works fine.

The CI is running on a Google Cloud Engine instance and we use JRuby.

Answer (score 0):

Rubygems acknowledged an issue with their CDN and rolled out a fix. See http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/21197-503-connection-timeout.

Meanwhile, we had changed our CI slave instances from EU to US as a workaround for this issue.